# has no MX record

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, freeipa

I have two servers running CentOS release 6.5 (Final).
In one of them is installed FreeIPA:

```
Name: freeipa.fi.example.com 
IP: 192.168.99.50
```

And the other Zimbra as mail server:

```
Name: freeipa.fi.example.com 
IP: 192.168.99.2
```

In FreeIPA I created a mx record and then update changes.

The dns works well for both servers not so with mx registry:

```
nslookup freeipa.fi.example.com
Server:     192.168.99.50
Address:    192.168.99.50#53
```

---

```
Name:   freeipa.fi.example.com
Address: 192.168.99.50
```

---

```
nslookup zimbra2014.fi.example.com
Server:     192.168.99.50
Address:    192.168.99.50#53

Name:   zimbra2014.fi.example.com
Address: 192.168.99.2
```

---

```
nslookup 
> set q=mx
> fi.example.com
Server:     192.168.99.50
Address:    192.168.99.50#53

*** Can't find fi.example.com: No answer
```

---

In fact, the query doesn't work for the zone:

```
nslookup fi.example.com
Server:     192.168.99.50
Address:    192.168.99.50#53

*** Can't find fi.example.com: No answer
```

---

Add information from my records:

```
@
NS
freeipa.fi.example.com.

MX
MX
1 zimbra2014

_kerberos
TXT
FI.EXAMPLE.COM

_kerberos-master._tcp
SRV
0 100 88 freeipa

_kerberos-master._udp
SRV
0 100 88 freeipa

_kerberos._tcp
SRV
0 100 88 freeipa

_kerberos._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs
SRV
0 100 88 freeipa

_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs
SRV
0 100 88 freeipa

_kerberos._udp
SRV
0 100 88 freeipa

_kerberos._udp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs
SRV
0 100 88 freeipa

_kerberos._udp.dc._msdcs
SRV
0 100 88 freeipa

_kpasswd._tcp
SRV
0 100 464 freeipa

_kpasswd._udp
SRV
0 100 464 freeipa

_ldap._tcp
SRV
0 100 389 freeipa

_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs
SRV
0 100 389 freeipa

_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs
SRV
0 100 389 freeipa

cliubuntu
A
192.168.99.100
SSHFP
1 1 910E5A8D2BFDC24FCBEA45B226C4207FE81C86FD
SSHFP
1 2 618A4FBDB24C7901419994277CA661D7D16428D6A5F411D64EB4F487 07144CFC
SSHFP
3 1 CEEDC3C8A58D7DE59C8F60FCBDF13CCBF19F35D4
SSHFP
3 2 C1AA6110C2E488728D38B655ADC8D9700B6A409998FC7740A58BC0D8 EAC8F430
SSHFP
2 1 E2D3038DEA31D5083E1778204BD9F1EF9A6FE732
SSHFP
2 2 3F10D2F1ABFBDB8FB3460010D18B8ABD9E370CD2324362A7C31579C5 0E9BF8C0

freeipa
A
192.168.99.50
SSHFP
1 1 462CCB5D17640703E0731BCF4A1454862967EEA3
SSHFP
2 1 65517CB8AB7ABAC3A27E9F4700071AFC09D165EF

zimbra2014
A
192.168.99.2
MX
1 zimbra2014
SSHFP
1 1 04DA2757EC4999C2609D1706F622EF18F4A86654
SSHFP
2 1 E671A5DD87C98EFCBC966899454FAAA620720F51

SSHFP
1 1 15D9E62B7D6169544C6F28BC385E2F482C6E92E4
SSHFP
2 1 6881D66C21E879DA5A0C6B1732A2EB02BC347CAC
```

I've been looking for a long time and I still can't fix it.
Do you suspect that is missing in this configuration?.

I appreciate so much your help :). 
Greetings!.

Comment: This would have been easier to figure out with a screenshot, but I still think the downvotes are mostly unfair.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a long shot, and I am no avid DNS admin, but I have set up a dns server a few times for my intranet.
I sometimes don't get the `dns` server of my intranet to resolve addresses - especially after I manually append some new permanent dns entry.

The problem in those cases is some mix up in the `.jnl` files. what I do in those cases is

1. stop dns server
2. remove `*.jnl` files from /var/named/
3. start `dns` server again.

Comment: What are these files supposed to be? I have none of them on my FreeIPA DNS server.

Comment: these are journal files for the BIND DNS server. I presume you are running BIND. are you not?

Comment: Thanks for the replies
The folder exists but not the files. 
Reboot and still no working.
I'm newbie with FreeIPA, guess background uses BIND, but I'm not sure.
Just install and configure FreeIPA, this enables the use of DNS.

Comment: @Michael The jnl files are for transactional data, mostly used in DDNS and on masters/slaves performing IXFRs. (actual ones, not AXFR-as-IXFR) You're not supposed to blow away the journal files after manaully appending data; you're supposed to use the `rndc freeze example.com` → edit → `rndc thaw example.com` workflow.

Comment: I could solve it. 
Add a record type A but for @.
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about FreeIPA, but I know BIND well as I work ( at least part of the time ) as a DNS admin for my company.

In the zone file you show above it appears as though the MX  record appears after the NS record but I don't see a specification for what the zone is. I would check to make sure FreeIPA knows what your parent zone is (fi.example.com) and once you do that I suspect the MX records will show up.

Does the same thing happen when you try to look up NS records?  Based on what I see it probably will.

In BIND you can specify a $ORIGIN at the start to tell BIND that this file is for X (example.com in my example) domain.  Once that's established you can then tell it where things like the NS and MX records are.

Here's a simple example I found on CentOS' website:

(from http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-bind-zone.html)

```
$ORIGIN example.com. 
$TTL 86400 

@   IN  SOA dns1.example.com.   hostmaster.example.com. (
        2001062501 ; serial                     
        21600      ; refresh after 6 hours                     
        3600       ; retry after 1 hour                     
        604800     ; expire after 1 week                     
        86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day  


IN  NS  dns1.example.com.       
IN  NS  dns2.example.com.        


IN  MX  10  mail.example.com.       
IN  MX  20  mail2.example.com.        

server1 IN  A   10.0.1.5        
server2 IN  A   10.0.1.6

dns1    IN  A   10.0.1.5        
dns1    IN  A   10.0.1.6
```

The part I was interested in showing was the MX records "IN MX", which here shows mail.example.com as the MX for example.com.  Like i said above, make sure FreeIPA knows what your parent zone is and see if that helps.

Comment: FreeIPA feeds records into LDAP, and bind picks them up through [an LDAP driver](https://fedorahosted.org/bind-dyndb-ldap/) (which bind also writes updates to, which come in fron nsupdate).

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I see the problem now. You have given the hostname `MX` an MX record.

The MX record should be attached to the domain, and not have an individual hostname (unless you are trying to divert mail for a subdomain, which is rare).

To resolve the problem, delete the invalid record and add the MX record to the `@` name.

[image: FreeIPA DNS configuration]